# Query en MYSQL tarda 160 segundos en ejecutarse.. ayuda porfavor

Tags: mysql

Esta es la query en cuestión, es de un theme de Wordpress

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.*
FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.id = wp_postmeta.post_id)
LEFT JOIN wp_options ON wp_options.option_name LIKE Concat('_ait_directory2_elements_opts_page_', wp_posts.id)
WHERE 1 = 1
  AND (((((Find_in_set(wp_posts.id,
                         (SELECT DISTINCT Group_concat(post_id) AS ids
                          FROM wp_postmeta AS postmeta
                          WHERE postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%r%'
                            AND postmeta.meta_key IN ('subtitle', 'features_search_string') )))
          OR (wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%r%')
          OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%r%')))
        OR ((option_value LIKE '%r%'))))
  AND (wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_ait-item_item-featured')
  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'ait-item'
  AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
       OR wp_posts.post_author = 58
       AND wp_posts.post_status = 'private')
GROUP BY wp_posts.id
ORDER BY Cast(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) DESC, wp_posts.post_date ASC LIMIT 0, 5;
```

en mysqltuner me dice que tengo una query sin index y ya he configurado todo el `my.cnf` bien, pero no se que más hacer

Comment: Puedes pegar el código por favor?

Comment: ya la he puesto ahi, gracias

Comment: ¿Con qué objetivo estás haciendo un `group_concat()` para luego usarlo en un `find_in_set()`? No podés evaluarlo directamente desde la subconsulta sin agrupadores?

Comment: como se haría eso? es un theme de wordpress y yo no tengo mucha idea de este tipo de querys :S

Comment: dev, bienvenid@! Te invito a pasar por el [tour de bienvenida](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y [este](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) link para tener en cuenta al momento de formular preguntas, puede que te interese [este](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) que trata de que hacer al momento de recibir una respuesta.
Si has encontrado una respuesta por tu cuenta, puede que te interese ver [esto](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Por otra parte, no queda claro, si quieres usar la query por tu cuenta (la tomaste del theme) o si estás usando el theme en cuestión. Si es esto último, ¿cuál es el theme en cuestión? ¿Verificaste sus prerrequisitos?

Comment: hola asiduo, es una query que traia el theme, todo el mundo tiene lentitud con el buscador, pero yo al tener como 300.000 directorios me tarda 160 segundos.. y estoy seguro que debe haber alguna forma de optimizar esa query, pero no lo consigo llevo todo el dia con ello, los requisitos del theme estan bien

Comment: Utiliza @nombreUsarioSinEspacios para responder a alguien en particular. Recién ahora revisando veo que me respondiste.

Comment: Sugerencias para poder brindarte algo más de ayuda. Edita tu pregunta e incluye: nombre del theme y link (para referencia), el resultado de mysqltuner y del explain plan de la query (si no sabes como hacerlo mira [aquí](http://informaticafrustrada.es/pildoritas-de-bases-de-datos-optimizacion-explain-plan/))